# how to declare R.color as a constant or retrieve it from the resources?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-resources

Is there any way to declare the `selector` of the `listview` as constant in my activity or refer to that constant from resurces.

I have the following `drawerList.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_red_light);` and i want to declare `holo_red_light` as constant in my activity or to retrieve it from thr resources, is it possible?

Comment: Make `color.xml` file in `res` folder and retrieve that from it..

Answer (score 1):

create color.xml in res->values folder

and add following tag

```
<color name="holo_color">#YOUR COLOR HEX VALUE</color>
```

Comment: ok but how to reference it from "drawerList.setSelector(android.R.);"

Comment: drawerList.setSelector(R.color.holo_color);

Answer (score 0):

You can find the color value [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/colors.xml), for example. Its hex value is `#ffff4444`. All you have to do now is to put the following:

`<color name="holo_red_light">#ffff4444</color>`

in one of your resource files, preferably `colors.xml`.

---

*EDIT*

Create a new file in your `res/values` folder and call it `colors.xml`. It should look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="holo_red_light">#ffff4444</color>
</resources>
```

Then, in your `Activity`, you could do this:

`drawerList.setSelector(R.color.holo_red_light);`

Note that there is no `android.` prepend before `R` - this is because the color you’re referencing is in your `res` folder. You might need to import the `R` class (which should be trivial).

Comment: ok but how to reference it from "drawerList.setSelector(android.R.);"

Comment: I’m sorry, I don’t understand what you’re trying to reference. Are you asking how to get the selector `Drawable` once it is set? Or how to access it from your own `res` folder?

Comment: i mean after declaring the color in the res/colors folder. now i want to write in the code in the activity reference that color, e.g: drawerList.setSelector(android.R.  is it possible